# Add a callback to a Vue instance's destroy hook

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a Map where the keys are instances of Vue components, like:

```
const instanceA = new Vue({...});
const instanceB = new Vue({...});

const register = new Map();
function registerInstance(instance){
    register.set(instance, []);
}
```

How can I hook a callback to the destruction of a Vue component? I would like that when the component is being destroyed I would remove it's reference from my `Map` register. Something like:

```
function registerInstance(instance){
    register.set(instance, []);
    instance.onDestroy(() => {
        register.set(instance, null);
        register.delete(instance);
    });
}
```

That would do a proper cleanup to avoid memory leaks, but not sure how to add a callback to a Vue instance's destruction process...

I do not want to add this logic in each component's `beforeDestroy` or `destroyed` functions. I would like to add them from outside the component, just using its instance pointer...

---

I thought about overriding instance.beforeDestroyed with a function that calls my code and then the original instance.beforeDestroyed from the instance. But that feels very wrong

Comment: @Estradiaz I am aware of mixins, thank you. But that is prior to the components instanciation. I want to add to a already instanciated component.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

OK, looks like we can use `instance.$once("hook:beforeDestroy", () => {` to add callbacks to hooks!

A example would be:

```js
const instance = new Vue({});

instance.$once("hook:beforeDestroy", () => {
  console.log('Destroying!');
});

setTimeout(() => {
  instance.$destroy();
}, 1000);
```

```html
<script src="https://vuejs.org/js/vue.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: In Vue 3 `$once` will be removed, but you can use the composition API instead.